# Flume configuration not working showing exception

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I have the followinf flume configuration. I am trying to transfer a file of size 9GB to hdfs using flume from spool directory. I have the following flume configuration.

```
    #initialize agent's source, channel and sink
wagent.sources = wavetronix
wagent.channels = memoryChannel2
wagent.sinks = flumeHDFS

# Setting the source to spool directory where the file exists
wagent.sources.wavetronix.type = spooldir
wagent.sources.wavetronix.spoolDir = /johir/WAVETRONIX/output/Yesterday
wagent.sources.wavetronix.fileHeader = false
wagent.sources.wavetronix.basenameHeader = true
#agent.sources.wavetronix.fileSuffix = .COMPLETED

# Setting the channel to memory
wagent.channels.memoryChannel2.type = memory
# Max number of events stored in the memory channel
wagent.channels.memoryChannel2.capacity = 50000
agent.channels.memoryChannel2.batchSize = 1000
wagent.channels.memoryChannel2.transactioncapacity = 1000

# Setting the sink to HDFS
wagent.sinks.flumeHDFS.type = hdfs
#agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.useLocalTimeStamp = true
wagent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.path =/user/root/WAVETRONIXFLUME/%Y-%m-%d/
wagent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true
wagent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.filePrefix= %{basename}
wagent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream

# Write format can be text or writable
wagent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text

# use a single csv file at a time
wagent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.maxOpenFiles = 1

wagent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.rollCount=0
wagent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.rollInterval=0
wagent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 6400000
wagent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.batchSize =1000

# never rollover based on the number of events
wagent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 0

# rollover file based on max time of 1 min
#agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
# agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.idleTimeout = 600

# Connect source and sink with channel
wagent.sources.wavetronix.channels = memoryChannel2
wagent.sinks.flumeHDFS.channel = memoryChannel2
```

But I am getting the following exception.

> Exception in thread "SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor"
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>           at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1043)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1535)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.getClassLoadingLock(ClassLoader.java:463)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:404)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           at org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.(LoggingEvent.java:165)
>           at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
>           at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
>           at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.warn(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:479)
>           at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.process(HDFSEventSink.java:461)
>           at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
>           at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Please edit the file `${FLUME_HOME}/conf/flume-env.sh`, then add following code:

`export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1000m -Xmx12000m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"`

You can adjust the options "Xmx" and "Xms".